# systemd service: restart on start-pre timeout

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service with an exceptionally long `ExecStartPre` command, making sure DNS resolving works before the service starts. I would like to have the service restart every time it times out from this command (basically until DNS works). I got this snippet from [here](https://serverfault.com/a/867845/968608).

Yes, I realize that setting `TimeoutStartSec` can increase the startup timeout, allowing the ExecStartPre command to finish running. This technically works, but I am looking for something different: a way to continually restart the service until `ExecStartPre` doesn't take >90s.

So far, I've tried a configuration with `Restart=on-abnormal` and one with `Restart=on-failure`, hoping that they would catch the timeout. They didn't. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Service file:

```ini
[Unit]
Description=thing
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c 'until host google.com; do sleep 1; done'
ExecStart=python ...script.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=60
...

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Log after reboot:

```
-- Boot 16978e49888146259f843055bfa26399 --
Oct 03 02:26:05 thing systemd[1]: Starting thing...
Oct 03 02:26:15 thing sh[609]: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Oct 03 02:26:26 thing sh[934]: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Oct 03 02:26:37 thing sh[973]: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Oct 03 02:26:48 thing sh[1003]: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Oct 03 02:27:00 thing sh[1038]: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Oct 03 02:27:11 thing sh[1066]: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Oct 03 02:27:22 thing sh[1101]: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Oct 03 02:27:33 thing sh[1131]: ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
Oct 03 02:27:35 thing systemd[1]: thing.service: start-pre operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 03 02:27:35 thing systemd[1]: thing.service: Control process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Oct 03 02:27:35 thing systemd[1]: thing.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Oct 03 02:27:35 thing systemd[1]: Failed to start thing.
```